# Redux TODO tutorial, state is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm following the Redux tutorial and making a simple TODO app. The application has already have a few pages and reducers. This noted i can't get all the todos ( i call them goals ) because they are not defined. Does someone have an idea?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { toggleGoal } from 'containers/CounterPage/actions'
import GoalList from 'components/GoalList'


const getVisibleGoals = (goals, filter) => {
  console.log(goals)
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return goals
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return goals.filter(g => g.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return goals.filter(g => !g.completed)
    default:
      return goals
  }
}

const mapStateToProps  = (state) => {
    return {
      goals: getVisibleGoals(state.goals, state.visibilityFilter)
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onGoalClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleGoal(id))
    }
  }
}
const VisibleGoal =  connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(GoalList);

export default VisibleGoal
```

REDUCER

```
/*
 *
 * CounterPage reducer
 *
 */

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const goal = (state = {} , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_GOAL':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_GOAL':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: !state.completed
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const goals = (state = [] , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_GOAL':
      return [
        ...state,
        goal(undefined, action)
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_GOAL':
      return state.map(t =>
        goal(t, action)
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const visibilityFilter = (state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const counterPageReducer = combineReducers({
  goals,
  visibilityFilter
})

export default counterPageReducer;
```

OUTPUT CONSOLE

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'goals' of undefined
    at mapStateToProps (eval at ./app/containers/VisibleGoal/index.js
```

STATE TREE
[image: STATE]

Look at the console log. The state works but not getting the goals out of the state. The error says that it can't map undefined

Comment: Please post your reducer and the output of the console log

Comment: @FabioCosta Updated

Comment: Are you sure that error is from the right place? It's saying that `state` is undefined (cannot read property 'goals' of undefined)

Comment: @DominicTobias As you see i map goals as props to GoalList. GoalList then maps over all the goals and creates the Goal themselves. But GoalList is getting undefined instead of the goals. Check the console.log's. I can console.log the state but not console.log the state.goals

Comment: @DominicTobias I just tried state.counterPage.goals but that doesn't work either

Comment: As the error says it's not the `goals` that is undefined here, but the `state`.

Comment: @OstapMaliuvanchuk how, based on the state, should i get the goals?

Comment: @ThibaultLesuisse you don't seem to have `state` at the first place. From the log message` Cannot read property 'goals' of undefined` it looks like `state` is undefined. So the problem is not that there is not `goals` in state, but that there is no `state` at all. Looking at it again it looks like the syntax is wrong. You have `const mapStateToProps  = (state) => ({...})`. Try to remote parentheses and make it like  `const mapStateToProps  = (state) => {...}`.

Comment: do you have an github repo for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change the way the goals were retrieved from the state

```
const mapStateToProps  = (state) => {
    return {
      goals: getVisibleGoals(state.get('counterPage').goals, state.get('counterPage').visibilityFilter)
    }
}
```

State.get('counterPage').goals -> because of the combinedReducer